# Return the root directory of Delphi executable

Tags: delphi, directory, root, delphi-xe8

I have a Delphi application executing and when I call `GetCurrentDir` the following  returns:

> C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo\Win32\Debug

When I call `ExtractFileDir(GetCurrentDir())` I receive the following:

> C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo\Win32

What I desire is `C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo`

```
function RetRoot: string;
var
  i: Integer;
  buf: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  buf := ExtractFileDir(GetCurrentDir());
  i := Length(buf);
  repeat
    dec(i);
  until (buf[i] = '\') or (i < 3);
  if buf[i] = '\' then
  begin
    Delete(buf, i, Length(buf));
    Result := buf;
  end;
end;
```

I wrote this function to get the desired result.  I would like to know if there is a better approach to accomplish retrieving the root directory of a Delphi executable.

Comment: I suppose you need to define what you mean by the root directory of a Delphi executable. Suppose you copy the executable to a folder under the program files directory, as you would if you installed it. What would be the root directory. FWIW, the current directory is only coincidentally the same directory as the executable is in. It does not have to be. Your text processing code is very needless. You can delete it all and replace with standard function calls.

Comment: So, you might write `ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))` to get the directory containing the executable. And to step up two directories `ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))))`. But why would you want to step up two directories? That seems plain weird. If you want better help, then you should explain what you are going to do with this information.

Comment: David I believe I know how to do these things.  Your response was outstanding.  I have not had the time to look into your offering further due to continual fire calls.  Where is the documentation explaining the things you mention?  Thanks Arch

Comment: "*C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo\Win32\Debug ... What I desire is C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo*" - why?  `BCSLBDemo` is your **project root**, not your **executable root**.  Your **executable** is running from the `Win32\Debug` folder, because that is where the **project** is configured to output the executable that it creates. The **executable** has no concept of the **project**.  So what are you *really* trying to accomplish by having the **executable** find the **project** root? What is it going to do with that path?

Comment: I need a location to load a control from a text file.  When I place the zip on Embarcadero Code Central I never include the 32 bit nor the 64 bit executable directories.  Therefore that text file needs a home other than the executable's root.  Options are later made available to update that text file.   This approach eliminates the need to recompile the application due to file content modification.

Comment: You have clearly got the wrong solution in that case. Possible choices would be the same directory as executable, or a directory under the application data or program data folders.

Comment: There is no such thing as **"root directory of a Delphi executable"**. Your desired dir is `..\..`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's another way:

```
ExpandFileName(GetCurrentDir + '\..\..\'); // Current folder
ExpandFileName(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName) + '\..\..\'); // Exe folder
```

> C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo

Will take you two levels up as you can see.

Of course this only answer the "how to get 2 levels up" question. The question about Exe root is kind of non-sense. You might just need to configure your project settings to not make the `Win32\Debug` folders or move your data files into there ;-)

Answer (score 15):

You can obtain the full path to an application executable using:

```
ParamStr(0);
```

For a form based application, you have also the `Application` object available:

```
Application.ExeName;
```

To get the path to the file without the file name, you may consider to use [ExtractFileDir](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileDir) or [ExtractFilePath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFilePath).

The difference between the two is that `ExtractFilePath` retuns the path with the last delimiter (`/` or `\`) and `ExtractFileDir` truncates it.

---

As stated in the [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869919/return-the-root-directory-of-delphi-executable#comment53571810_32869919), multiple calls to `ExtractFileDir` allow to get the parent directory:

Having `C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe` you can obtain `C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo` like this:

```
ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))));
```

Comment: Do you know how `Application.ExeName` is implemented? It is `ParamStr(0)`. So why make the distinction?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan answer modified O:-)

Comment: Did you read the part of the question that said, *What I desire is “C:\dev\w32\2015\BCSLBDemo”*? Did you read my comments above?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes but the multiple calls to `ExtractFileDir` are already stated in your comment...

Comment: Important: Application.ExeName only exists in VCL applications at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the full path to an application executable using:

Delphi 2010 declare Uses
SWSystem;

Delphi Xe declare Uses
IWSystem ;

showmessage(gsAppPath);

Answer (score 1):

you can use $(RUN) (Runtime Variable) :

```
function Get_AppPath: string;
begin
  Result := ExtractFilePath(TPath.GetFullPath('$(RUN)'));
end;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this returns the CWD of the current process, not the path to the executable running. So it might be different depending on the directory you invoke the executable from.